# Change Image in Single Div with Toggle?

Tags: jquery, css, addclass, toggleclass

Wanted to to try to control the state of this sprite via toggles on three separate links. I have three separate links, and I figured I can click any link at to toggle one either one or off. The goal is the change the state of the #case image.

Was thinking that I can use addClass, but I don't know how to remove whatever class was put on there before. Assuming it's some variable right?

> ```
>   $("li.ti-color a").click(function(){
>       $("#logo-link").toggleClass('red');
>
>       });
>
>   $("li.black-pvd a").click(function(){
>       $("#logo-link").toggleClass('blue');
>
>
>   });
>
>   $("li.white-color a").click(function(){
>       $("#logo-link").toggleClass('white');
>
>
>   });
> ```

```
<div id="case">

    <a href="#" id="logo-link"></a>

</div>


<ul id="links"></li>
    <li class="black-pvd"><a href="#">Black PVD</a></li>
    <li class="ti-color"><a href="#">Titanium</a></li>
    <li class="white-color"><a href="#">White</a></li>

</ul>
```

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 3):

RemoveClass() works: http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

```
$("li.ti-color a").click(function(){
  $('#logo-link').removeClass('blue white').addClass('red');
});

$("li.black-pvd a").click(function(){
  $('#logo-link').removeClass('red white').addClass('blue');
});

$("li.white-color a").click(function(){
  $('#logo-link').removeClass('red blue').addClass('white');
});
```

Or if you want to replace all existing classes with another class, we can use .attr('class', 'white').  Like:

```
$("li.ti-color a").click(function(){
  $('#logo-link').attr('class', 'red');
});

$("li.black-pvd a").click(function(){
  $('#logo-link').attr('class', 'blue');
});

$("li.white-color a").click(function(){
  $('#logo-link').attr('class', 'white');
});
```

Comment: So you can just removeClass('all classes that i want turned off')

Comment: Yes, just a space between each classname.